# DevExpress InvalidDeploymentException during drag and drop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop, devexpress-windows-ui

When I drag and drop text from one DevExpress rich edit control to another, very often the program will crash with the exception thrown: "System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException" and an exit code of 0xc0000409 (which Google tells me is a Status_Stack_Buffer_Overflow, maybe, or maybe any fail fast error). I'll add that the crash occurs during the drag, before I have a chance to drop it.
The only thing I can find on the DevExpress site is a claim that I can safely ignore InvalidDeploymentExceptions because they are handled internally. I've told Visual Studio to ignore them, and nothing doing. I've tried handling unhandled exceptions, but apparently fail fast errors fail too fast for that. Any ideas what the problem might be or what I can do about it?

Comment: Update your question with the drag and drop code and highlight line where exception occurs

Comment: What code? The drag and drop operation is done by the DevExpress control. I'm not doing any event handling during the operation, and the VS debugger does not step in to tell me where the error occurred; the program just exits. I've now reinstalled DevExpress, and the issue is not recurring, but I thought I had it resolved once before, and it returned, so I'm not sure that has done it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.